# Split String on specific substring and keeping it

Tags: python, string, dataframe, split

I'm trying to update my DataFrame column 'Info' which contains Strings

example of the value of the 1st row :

```
df['Info'].values[0]
```

> ```
> 'XY  AL#2 Ext AL1 AL#3 Ext AL1 AL#4 Ext AL1 AL#5 Ext AL1'
> ```

I would like to split each row on **AL#** so that i get this results :

> ```
> ['XY',  'AL#2', 'Ext AL1', 'AL#3', 'Ext AL1' ,'AL#4', 'Ext AL1', 'AL#5' ,'Ext AL1']
> ```

I tried differents ways (*for example* : `df['Info].str.split()` etc.) but i didn't find a solution or the questions are on *C++* or *JAVA* answers.

any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try splitting using space and use compare operations like,

```
string = 'XY  AL#2 Ext AL1 AL#3 Ext AL1 AL#4 Ext AL1 AL#5 Ext AL1'

temp = st.split(" ")
string_arr = []
temp_string = ""
for i in temp:

  if "AL#" in i:
    string_arr.append(temp_string)
    string_arr.append(i)
    temp_string = ""
else:
    temp_string +=" " + i

print(string_arr) # result
```

gives result = [' XY ', 'AL#2', ' Ext AL1', 'AL#3', ' Ext AL1', 'AL#4', ' Ext AL1', 'AL#5']